# TOTP / FreeRADIUS on pfsense - Authentication Failed error

Tags: pfsense, google, freeradius

I am setting up freeradius on pfsense with the google authenticator option following this guide:
https://blog.vonhewitt.com/2017/08/pfsense-openvpn-setup-with-freeradius3p3/

However, when I test the authentication under diagnostics > authentication I get the error "authentication failed" when entering username and PIN+OTP as the password. I have blown everything away and rebuilt to no avail. I have tried multiple TOTP google authenticator type apps for the generation of the OTP codes. No one in the #pfsense nor #freeradius IRC chans on freenode had any ideas as to why either. Help me stackexchange-kenobi, you're my only hope..

Answer (score 0):

So, there is an issue with the pfsense GUI reporting authentication failed even when it is not truly failing. Also, any of the CHAP options appear to be failing right now as well. So, you will need to PAP in the System>User Manager>Authentication Servers menu. Then just connect freeRADIUS to the VPN service like normal and everything should just work; even though it will still show authentication failures if you try to check it in the diagnostics>authentication menu. Hopefully these issues will get resolved in the near future.